# Absolute UriSource of a Resource image

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, uri

I have a WPF project. If I store image in {ProjectRoot}\Images\image.png, and compile it as Resource then I can access it from a xaml (this xaml is located at Root) as BitmapImage by `BitmapImage UriSource="Images/image.png"`. But if I move the xaml to another folder, say {ProjectRoot}\Xamls, now I have to use `BitmapImage UriSource="../Images/image.png"`. Is there a way to specify an absolute project path, so that I can refer to them with the same path regardless of the location of the xaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this syntax both to reference by an absolute path inside the same project, or reference files in other projects:

```
UriSource="/MyAssemblyName;component/Images/image.png"
```

Here "MyAssemblyName" is the project/dll/exe name and "component" indicates the project root.

Comment: What do you mean by `component indicates the project root`? Is something meant to be put in place of `component`, or should the actual word be used? Not able to get this working.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)